# How to quote or summarise text from a reference that includes citations in Harvard Style?

Tags: citations, writing-style, cross-referencing

I am very much confused on referencing a paragraph and have tried to find an answer on YouTube but that didn't help!

So here is my question:

1. The lines from an article (author = aaa bbb) says: (example)

> Birmingham is a beautiful city as it sits in middle of the country
>   (ABC, 2010), has people from a lot cultures (DEF, 2012), has nice food
>   (GHI, 2011) and etc (FGH, 2013).

Now can I reference it like this?

> BBB (2014) highlights that birmingham is a beautiful city as it sits
>   in middle of the country (ABC, 2010), has people from a lot cultures
>   (DEF, 2012), has nice food (GHI, 2011) and etc (FGH, 2013).

Or can I just copy paste the original text as it already contains the references?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options.  The first option is to quote the paragraph and include all it's citations.  But you must include these cited works in your own bibliography.

The second option is to quote the paragraph and omit it's embedded citations. But you should add this note at the end of the quotation: "[citations from original have been omitted]"

Using your example, option 1 looks like this:

> As described by BBB (2014): "Birmingham is a beautiful city as it sits in middle of the country (ABC 2010), has people from a lot cultures (DEF 2012), has nice food (GHI 2011) and etc (FGH 2013)."
>
> BIBLIOGRAPHY
>
> ABC (2010), ...
>
> BBB (2014), ...
>
> DEF (2012), ...
>
> GHI (2011), ...
>
> FGH (2013), ...

Option 2 looks like this:

> As described by BBB (2014): "Birmingham is a beautiful city as it sits in middle of the country, has people from a lot cultures, has nice food and etc." [citations from original omitted]
>
> BIBLIOGRAPHY
>
> BBB (2014), ...

---

The preferred choice depends on the purpose of your writing, including the formality, the nature of the material you are quoting, and the reader.  Generally, choose option 1 if you are writing formally (in a dissertation or journal article) and if the citations in the original are very important to your reader.  Choose option 2 of omitting the citations improves readability and none of the embedded citations are relevant or important to your reader or your purposes.