# Should I cite the citations made in a quotation in the bibliography as well?

Tags: citations

Should I cite the citations made in a quotation in the bibliography?

Here is a fictitious text illustrating the situation:

> The authors Dupont & Albert (2019: 23) recall: "The resources of the
> country started to plummet at the end of the first era (e.g. Paxton
> 1982; Hurlish & Planck 1976; Deplon 1967)."

Here, **my** citation is (Dupont & Albert 2019), so it should of course be in my bibliography.

But what about the references made in the quotation from (Dupont & Albert 2019), that is : Paxton 1982; Hurlish & Planck 1976; Deplon 1967?

Should they also be in my bibliography?

Comment: Why wouldn't you? Also, perhaps you could name a (wide) field?

Comment: Why are you citing a secondary source? Is there something to be gained by citing Dupont & Albert? In my experience you would cite the claims themselves directly, not secondary authors who are themselves citing the claims. In general, you don’t cite a resource just because you first read it there; you cite it so that your readers can follow the chain of knowledge, and secondary sources disrupt that chain.

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/24424/17254

Comment: The main reason for quoting Dupont & Albert would be if you are specifically analyzing their argument and their use of evidence (e.g. if reviewing their book). It's not clear from the question what you're doing.

Comment: I have started to write an answer, but then decided it is mostly covered by other SE answers. TL;DR: only cite Dupont & Albert if it adds something to the original sources (https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/crediting-sources-one-has-found-citations-from, https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/42440/is-it-okay-to-incorporate-a-block-of-citations-from-a-review-paper-into-my-own-p). The prime example would be citing survey papers, although the 40-year gap makes it a bit unlikely in this specific example.

Comment: More apparent controversy here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/65670/should-i-cite-a-paper-for-its-literature-review/65706#65706

Comment: (The paper is in the humanities, language sciences) Thank you all for your answers. If I remove the quotation, and just paraphrase the text as "The authors Dupont & Albert (2019) recall that the resources started to finally disappear", I guess there is no need to include Paxton 1982; Hurlish & Planck 1976; Deplon 1967 in the bibliography?

Comment: @Stuart F, The illustration I gave is more about the structure, not the content. About the content, in my situation, the author (illustrated in my question by Dupont & Albert) makes a general statement about a stance that is hold in the literature (illustrated in my question by Paxton 1982; Hurlish & Planck 1976; Deplon 1967).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question will almost certainly depend upon the referencing style of the particular journal that you are writing for. For example the 6th edition of the Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association says in section 6.09, page 173:

> Do not omit *citations* embedded within the original material you are quoting ...

but then:

> The *works cited need not be* included in the list of references (unless you happen to cite them as primary sources elsewhere in your paper).

Despite the APA instructions there will doubtless be other referencing styles or journals that make a different choice.